# get cell by known NSIndexPath swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I wanted to do some feed like in Facebook. Feed i make like table view with customs cells. And added a panel in each cell, which u can drag down and find some more buttons. I added UIPanGestureRecognizer to it.  The problem is that when i'm programming Gesture i cannot get cell where i m dragging. Rowdidselected doesn't work. I need to get a cell, so i can drag my panel and make some bounds, so it cannot be moved through full screen. Just about 30 down, not more. It will be cool, if i could change height of current row too

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    let possition = recognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
    var index : NSIndexPath? =     self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(possition)

    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x,
        y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the cell where your gesture registered? After you get the indexPath:

```
let cell: YourCellClass = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.doWhatever()
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried it. Like this
 var myPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(possition)!
        let cell : FeedCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(myPath)
I m getting the message - (UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'
I can not understand why this message appear.
P.S.
i tried it some time ago it was written like " uresolved MyPath"

Comment: Glad you got it to work!. Will you please mark this answer as accepted if it helped you get there?